# Foreign key insertion error SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have tried applying the foreign key in many ways, but I am getting the same error when inserting a row to my table which is:

```
INSERT INTO MEDICINE 
VALUES (50, 'PREDNISONE', '8 BOTTLES', 'N', 
        TO_DATE('12-MAR-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'), 
        TO_DATE('09-JAN-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'), 2);
```

I have created my table in many ways:

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICINE
(
    M_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    M_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    QUANTITY NUMBER,
    OTC VARCHAR2(1),
    EXPR DATE,
    LAST_AUDIT DATE,
    PT_ID NUMBER,

    CONSTRAINT fk_MED FOREIGN KEY (PT_ID)
    REFERENCES PHARM_TECH(PT_ID)
);
```

I've also tried:

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICINE
(
    M_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    M_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    QUANTITY NUMBER,
    OTC VARCHAR2(1),
    EXPR DATE,
    LAST_AUDIT DATE,
    PT_ID NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE MEDICINE
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PT_ID)
REFERENCES PHARM_TECH(PT_ID);
```

I've also attempted:

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICINE
(
     M_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
     M_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
     QUANTITY NUMBER,
     OTC VARCHAR2(1),
     EXPR DATE,
     LAST_AUDIT DATE,
     PT_ID NUMBER REFERENCES PHARM_TECH(PT_ID)
);
```

These all run fine and creates the table without issues, however, I keep receiving this error when inserting the row above:

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

What's causing this?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with foreign keys. `8 BOTTLES` simply isn't a number (which is the data type for the `quantity` column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert the value '8 BOTTLES' into column QUANTITY. The data type is Number not varchar. try 8 or try changing the datatype of column Quantity to varchar2